# OAuth + Twitter on Android: Callback fails

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter-client

My Android application uses Java OAuth library, found [here](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/) for authorization on Twitter. I am able to get a request token, authorize the token and get an acknowlegement but when the browser tries the call back url to reconnect with my application, it does not use the URL I provide in code, but uses the one I supplied while registering with Twitter.

Note:
1. When registering my application with twitter, I provided a hypothetical call back url:http://abz.xyc.com  and set the application type as browser.
2. I provided a callback url in my code "myapp" and have added an intent filter for my activity with Browsable category and data scheme as "myapp".
3. URL called when authorizing does contain te callback url, I specified in code.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Relevant Code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        OAuthAccessor client = defaultClient();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(client.consumer.serviceProvider.userAuthorizationURL + "?oauth_token="
                + client.requestToken + "&oauth_callback=" + client.consumer.callbackURL));

        startActivity(i);

    }

    OAuthServiceProvider defaultProvider()
    {
        return new OAuthServiceProvider(GeneralRuntimeConstants.request_token_URL,
                GeneralRuntimeConstants.authorize_url, GeneralRuntimeConstants.access_token_url);
    }

    OAuthAccessor defaultClient()
    {
        String callbackUrl = "myapp:///";
        OAuthServiceProvider provider = defaultProvider();
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new OAuthConsumer(callbackUrl,
                GeneralRuntimeConstants.consumer_key, GeneralRuntimeConstants.consumer_secret,
                provider);
        OAuthAccessor accessor = new OAuthAccessor(consumer);

        OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new HttpClient4());
        try
        {
            client.getRequestToken(accessor);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return accessor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null)
        {
            String access_token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
        }
    }

}
// Manifest file
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".FirstActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </application>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Twitter does not honor callbacks requested in OAuth requests ([Twitter API Announce](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/2086c8c5a12242ec/f7d06f563f022be9)) and will only redirect to the callback URL specified in the Application Settings (note that "localhost" is not allowed).

I assume you checked [Oauth-callback-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121329/oauth-callback-on-android) question.

*Android guesswork--*
After a bit of reading up, I see Android browser redirects MyApp:/// to your application and I'm guessing Twitter doesn't like this bespoke URI prefix. I'm no android developer but one suggestion I might make is to get "www.myapp.com" on the web and have a re-redirect there.

So have your OAuth return to `http://www.myapp.com/redirect.aspx?oauth_token=abc` and have that page redirect to `myapp:///oauth_token=...` (the desired result)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

1. Can you please cite a reference for your statement:
"Twitter does not honor callbacks requested in OAuth requests and will only redirect to the callback URL specified in the Application Settings (note that "localhost" is not allowed)."  

2. Yes, I did check the Oauth-callback-on-Android question and have set my application type(i.e Browser) accordingly.  

Thanks again.

Comment: Added link to Twitter API announce.

Comment: If callbacks requested in OAuth requests are not honored then how do I call my application back post authorization? Twitter doesnot accept Android-style URLs, these need to be overridden. What are the alternatives if the above doesnt work?
Please help.
[You're getting 10 points at the moment; 125 after you answer this last question :P]

Comment: Thanks for your time Ian; will try to figure our how to do this. Certainly, I will not be alone here...

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i have this working:

```
 String authURL = m_provider.retrieveRequestToken (m_consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
```

And in the Manifest:

```
    <activity android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name = "xxxx.android.xxxxx"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name   = "android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="tweet" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In this case the callback url will be: myapp://tweet

Comment: will u please tell me what is myapp is this application name and what to write in place of tweet

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're doing the correct thing and Twitter is screwing up by always accepting your registered callback URL.  Is there any way to change the registered URL?  Maybe you could re-register and try an Android callback next time, see what happens.

Comment: Yes, we can change the registered URL by clicking the EDIT Application settings button. I tried two different sets of URL without much luck maybe I will re-register and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trying to log in with the same account I made the Twitter app. After I logged in with my personal profile the call back works (so far).