# Giving OAuthCommunicationException

Tags: android, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Twitter API not accepting callback URL for Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163111/twitter-api-not-accepting-callback-url-for-android-app)

I am trying to get uri using the function retrieveRequestToken(consumer,CALLBACK_URI) then 
after sign in twitter use the access key.But retriveRequestToken() function throws exception.
I gave  the internet uses permission for the application but it does not work.

```
Logcat:
01-07 19:26:24.589: D/in(581): check1
01-07 19:26:24.691: D/communication(581): 4
01-07 19:26:24.691: W/System.err(581):   oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
01-07 19:26:24.691: W/System.err(581):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
01-07 19:26:24.702: W/System.err(581):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
private  static  final  String CALLBACK_URI = "OauthTwitter://twitt";
private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

private static CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;
private static DefaultOAuthProvider provider;

        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
                ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTHORIZE_URL);
        update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // showMyDialog();

                try {
                    Log.d("in","check1");
                    String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,CALLBACK_URI);
                    Log.d("uri", authUrl);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(authUrl)));
                } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("signerg","1");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("Notauths","2");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("authExceg","3");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("communication","4");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Do you have a working network connection and permission for the app to connect to the internet?