# OAuthCommunicationException for twitter android

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I followed the tutorial link here (http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/312.html) and it did not work. Then I downloaded the source and got it to run and work. When I put in my key and key secret though, it no longer works and I get an 'OAuthCommunicationException' in the app. I havent changed anything else, how can I get it working? Thanks

EDIT: Heres my stacktrace for the error.

```
07-07 18:56:47.835: W/System.err(586): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
07-07 18:56:47.835: W/System.err(586):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
07-07 18:56:47.835: W/System.err(586):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
07-07 18:56:47.845: W/System.err(586):  at com.marakana.oauth.MainActivity$OAuthAuthorizeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:114)
07-07 18:56:47.845: W/System.err(586):  at com.marakana.oauth.MainActivity$OAuthAuthorizeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-07 18:56:47.845: W/System.err(586):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-07 18:56:47.845: W/System.err(586):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-07 18:56:47.845: W/System.err(586):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-07 18:56:47.845: W/System.err(586):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-07 18:56:47.855: W/System.err(586):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-07 18:56:47.855: W/System.err(586):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-07 18:56:47.855: W/System.err(586): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
07-07 18:56:47.865: W/System.err(586):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
07-07 18:56:47.865: W/System.err(586):  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
07-07 18:56:47.875: W/System.err(586):  at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
07-07 18:56:47.875: W/System.err(586):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
07-07 18:56:47.885: W/System.err(586):  at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
07-07 18:56:47.895: W/System.err(586):  ... 9 more
```

Comment: On encountering an exception, you should always provide the full message with the stacktrace and a hint to the line causing the exception, otherwise it's hard to help you here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter API not accepting callback URL for Android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163111/twitter-api-not-accepting-callback-url-for-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

pls make source you change all fields which require in given demo like 
Consumer key,Consumer secret,Access token,Access token secret etc
see http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application