# twitter and code for android app

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

I have developed an app with Twitter integration. The problem is when the intent view goes to the twitter page and I write the user name and the password and click submit button. The page resend to other page and show me a code number.
How can i get this code number from my app?? thanksss

Comment: You have to set up your application to use callbacks.  Here are a few links to other SO questions covering the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121329/oauth-callback-on-android OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199357/oauth-twitter-on-android-callback-fails